# cordova error adding plugin "GET www/cordova.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND "

Tags: javascript, cordova

I do so:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add https://github.com/jonathannaguin/BarcodeScanner.git
cordova build
cordova prepare
```

when a file index.html console I get an error

```
"GET www/cordova.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND "
```

what am I doing wrong? How do I fix to work?

Comment: cordova js does not exist in www folder.

Comment: well, what can I do so that it appeared there?

Comment: just move the js file to www folder